# Laravel 5.7 Reformat Date Time Stamp in View

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

By default when Laravel creates a post it stores the date and time stamp as:
2019-01-31 23:32:06

How can I show it in the view as - Jan 31st, 2018 11:32pm?

Answer (score 0):

U can use [Php Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) in modifying date. eg.

```
$dt = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', '2019-02-01 03:45:27.612584');

// $dt->toAtomString() is the same as $dt->format(DateTime::ATOM);
echo $dt->toAtomString();           // 2019-02-01T03:45:27+00:00
echo $dt->toCookieString();         // Friday, 01-Feb-2019 03:45:27 UTC

echo $dt->toIso8601String();        // 2019-02-01T03:45:27+00:00
// Be aware we chose to use the full-extended format of the ISO 8601 norm
// Natively, DateTime::ISO8601 format is not compatible with ISO-8601 as it
// is explained here in the PHP documentation:
// https://php.net/manual/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.iso8601
// We consider it as a PHP mistake and chose not to provide method for this
// format, but you still can use it this way:
echo $dt->format(DateTime::ISO8601); // 2019-02-01T03:45:27+0000

echo $dt->toISOString();            // 2019-02-01T03:45:27.612584Z
echo $dt->toJSON();                 // 2019-02-01T03:45:27.612584Z

echo $dt->toIso8601ZuluString();    // 2019-02-01T03:45:27Z
echo $dt->toDateTimeLocalString();  // 2019-02-01T03:45:27
echo $dt->toRfc822String();         // Fri, 01 Feb 19 03:45:27 +0000
echo $dt->toRfc850String();         // Friday, 01-Feb-19 03:45:27 UTC
echo $dt->toRfc1036String();        // Fri, 01 Feb 19 03:45:27 +0000
echo $dt->toRfc1123String();        // Fri, 01 Feb 2019 03:45:27 +0000
echo $dt->toRfc2822String();        // Fri, 01 Feb 2019 03:45:27 +0000
echo $dt->toRfc3339String();        // 2019-02-01T03:45:27+00:00
echo $dt->toRfc7231String();        // Fri, 01 Feb 2019 03:45:27 GMT
echo $dt->toRssString();            // Fri, 01 Feb 2019 03:45:27 +0000
echo $dt->toW3cString();            // 2019-02-01T03:45:27+00:00
```

Kindly read more about [Php Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Comment: There is no way out of the box?  These dates are already stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting) in laravel.

First, use `carbon`:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

Then use the format you want, in your case, it would be like this:

```
public function test()
{
    $dt = User::find(1);
    return $dt->created_at->format('M jS\\, Y h:i:s A'); //Dec 1st, 1975 02:15:16 PM
}
```

You can also use it in your **view**, just use `carbon` at the top of your file:

`<?php use Carbon\Carbon;?>`

then change the format in your display like `{{$dt->created_at->format('M jS\\, Y h:i:s A')}}`

Answer (score 0):

Your input is `2018-01-31 23:32:06`.

Your expected output is `Jan 31st, 2018 11:32pm`.

I have created a function:

```
function convertToPreferedDateFormat($dateString='')
  {
            $toTimeString = strtotime($dateString);

            $yourExpectedFormat = 'M dS, Y h:ia';

           // $prettyBeautifullWay = 'l jS \of F Y h:i:s A';

            return date($yourExpectedFormat, $toTimeString);
  }
```

Then now testing

```
$timeString = '2018-01-31 23:32:06';

  $expectedOutput = 'Jan 31st, 2018 11:32pm';

echo convertToPreferedDateFormat($timeString);
echo "<br>";
echo $expectedOutput;
```